# How to customize SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message according to the error I get

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I made a login system with Spring Security.
This is my spring-security.xml

```
... 
<session-management invalid-session-url="/login">
       <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
</session-management>

<form-login 
        login-page="/login"                         
        default-target-url="/index" 
        always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"          
        username-parameter="j_username"         
        password-parameter="j_password" />

<logout
        logout-success-url="/login"          
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" 
        invalidate-session="true" />     
    ...
```

Since i have this line    `authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"`
I know that if     `error` is `'true'` there's an error: it might be "**bad credentials**" or "**Maximum sessions number exceeded**".But I'd like to know which error really occorred?

Is there a way, inside a java class (@controller), to know what kind of error Spring is giving me, in order to customize those error messages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this solution, it seems to work.

Extending `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` you can send the user to different pages, and print the message you want.

My main goal wasn't to "override" `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message` but was customizing the error message according to the various kind of errors Spring security gives me.

web.xml

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

security-config.xml (just some code)

**session-management**

```
   <session-management invalid-session-url="/login" session-authentication-error-url="/login" >
                   <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
            </session-management>
```

**form-login** where you call your own AuthenticationFailureHandler (customFailureHandler)

```
  <form-login 
                    login-page="/login"         
                    default-target-url="/index" 
                    always-use-default-target="true"                  
                    authentication-failure-handler-ref="customFailureHandler"   
                    username-parameter="j_username"         
                    password-parameter="j_password" />
```

the **bean** of your own AuthenticationFailureHandler

```
 <beans:bean id="customFailureHandler" class="com.springgestioneerrori.controller.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
```

and this is the class implementing SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationException;

public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler { 

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

     if(exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(BadCredentialsException.class)) {
            setDefaultFailureUrl("/url1");
      }
      else if (exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(DisabledException.class)) {         
          setDefaultFailureUrl("/url2");
      }
      else if (exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(SessionAuthenticationException.class)) {       
          setDefaultFailureUrl("/url3");    
      }

      super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);  

    }

}
```

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: The solution in general is pretty solid, but it is **very** bad practice to call setter in an overridden method to have custom behaviour happen in super method. There will be one instance of `CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler` for the entire application, so in a multi-threaded scenario there is no way of knowing what will happen (another thread might have called `setDefaultFailureUrl` before the first thread gets to execute `onAuthenticationFailure`). Making the method synchronized would solve the problem, but it would still be pretty nasty.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the authentication-failure-url, you need to use authentication-failure-handler-ref and refer the failure handler bean which you need to create and map different urls (or different params to the same url) to different type of exceptions.

```
 <form-login 
    login-page="/login"                         
    default-target-url="/index" 
    always-use-default-target="true"
    authentication-failure-handler-ref="customFailureHandler"          
    username-parameter="j_username"         
    password-parameter="j_password" />


<beans:bean id="customFailureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop
                key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">/url1</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop
                key="org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException">/url2</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="org.springframework.secuirty.authentication.DisabledException">/url3</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/url4" />
</beans:bean>
```

There are bunch of other exceptions, mentioned in the docs. Please refer the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticationException.html)

EDIT:

There is an exception for the same, SessionAuthenticationException is thrown typically because the same user has exceeded the number of sessions they are allowed to have concurrent. But this is at container level only and won't work if you have multiple containers.

```
<security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>

<bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
<bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy" >
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <property name="maximumSessions" value="2" />
 </bean>
```

Comment: Thank you man. Unfortunately there isn't any specific exception in case a user attempts to log in, at the same time, from many different devices (Maximum sessions number exceeded). How should I handle this case? I have no idea

Comment: I have edited the answer to include session control.

Comment: Thank you man. I have found another solution and i posted. Anyway yours was good!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but since the answer marked as correct actually contains a nasty subtle bug it should be noted that the correct solution would be to use built-in `ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler` instead of the `CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler` suggested in the answer from @mdp.